# How can I save data to permanent storage and retrieve it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to save data on device which it should be visible to user when he/she went to the desired path from file manager.

now I have two problem:

1-
like social networks which save images in storage ( not cache images ) , I want to save my images into desired path storage and the images should be accessable like cacheNetworkImage.
so what should I do ?

because I loads many images , caching them is not a good solution because it occupy a high amount of RAM.

2-
this scenario is like Previous but I download some media into my storage with some IDs.
but I a want to read only IDs and if user click on that file , execute it.
so How can I access name of existing files in that file of storage path ?

thanks to community. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Save a lot of data into the mobile storage is not a good practice, muy suggestion is consumed an API or use a cloud service like Azure or AWS to storage the data and later load the data you need on your mobile app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chose between basic [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) library and more advanced [network_to_file_image](https://pub.dev/packages/network_to_file_image) library.

In the first one you can list your files and read them this way:

```
void checkDirs() async{
  Directory tempDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  List<FileSystemEntity> directory = tempDir.listSync();
  directory.forEach((x) => debugPrint(x.path));
}

Future<File> readImage(String path) async{
  return File(path);
}
```

And render it this way:

```
Container(child: FutureBuilder<File>(
  future: readImage("some_path"),
  builder: (BuildContext context,
    AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState ==
      ConnectionState.done &&
      snapshot.data != null) {
      return Image.file(
        snapshot.data,
      );
    } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
      return const Text(
        'Error Picking Image',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    } else {
      return const Text(
        "No photo"
      );
    }
  },
))
```

The second one is well documented on the link.